# How can I paginate image files in a folder in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I am working on a webpage in JPS that allows you to load a zip file containing images so those images are merged into a pdf file so that the user can download the generated pdf.

So far I have managed to unzip the file in a folder on the server, but i wish to show the unzipped images as if those were pages of the pdf.

This is the code that tries to manage the displaying of those images:

```
    <div class="column">
    <%
      if(request.getParameter("desc")!=null){
         s = new File((String) request.getAttribute("onDesc"));
         // the method full() inserts the image addresses into an array called pages
         full(s);
         files = s.listFiles();
         if(files!=null && files.length>0){
           //gere i make the first paga be the first element on the array
           pagina = pages.get(0);
     %>
     <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
        <div>
           <Select name="item" class="paginator">
     <%
          for(int i=0; i<files.length;i++){
             pages.add(s.getName()+"/"+files[i].getName());
     %>
          <Option value="<%=i%>">
          <%=i+1%>
          </Option>
     <%
          }
     %>
          </select>
          <!--This button should show the image when you select a "page" in the combobox-->
          <input type="submit" value="VER" name="VER"/>
       </div>
       <div>
     <%      
        }
        if(request.getParameter("VER")!=null){
        try{
          String rs = request.getParameter("item"); 
          if(rs!=null){
             int dir = Integer.parseInt(rs);
             pagina = pages.get(dir);
      %>
        <img src="<%="desc/"+pagina%>" class="page">
      <%
          }
        }catch(Exception e){
      %>
        <!-- This is the part that gives me problems, as it only manages to show the first image I send but does not show the other images after the event of the button -->
        <img src="img/Photo-icon.png" class="page">
      <%
        }
      }
      %>
      </div>                 
     </form>
      <%
      }
      %>
    </div>
```

So, if anyone could explain what is it that I'm doing wrong or show a better way to deal with the issue so i can finish this little project. Meanwhile I will continue searching how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSP is supposed to be for viewing data (The V in the MVC paradigm) - move you data controlling logic to a servlet (The C  in the MVC paradigm)  - jquery may be of help to you

Comment: So you say I should also deal with the image "pagination" in a servlet instead of the jsp page?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to find plenty of examples on the web